# Apache Solr Restore API does not balance the data in shards at destination

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, solrcloud, solr4

I have a setup of Solr with 4 shards. Its version is 6.6.x. I have used backup API to take backup of Solr index from another instance (remote). Now when I store it on my new Solr (with 4 shards). All data is move in a single shard. Other shards are empty. Is something missed by me while restoring the index ?

How can I move data from one shard to other so that there should be equal number of documents

Comment: How are you restoring? The default behavior is that the number of shards and replicas should match what was being backed up. Are you talking about all the shards living on a single node, or is all the data in a _actual_ single shard (i.e. a single index). What does it look like before backing up and what does it look like after?

Comment: From source, there was one shard and on destination, these are 4.

Comment: Ah. Don't confuse shards and nodes. A shard is a part of an index; the number of nodes this will be replicated to, depends on the replicationFactor configured. Importing a backup will not split a shard into multiple other shards either, since the whole goal of a backup is to get back the same state as what was present when the backup happened.

Comment: You're probably going to have to do this manually (.. someone might have written a script to do it for you, but I don't remember the details) by issuing a split shard command, then move those new shards to new nodes.

Comment: Then how can I achieve it. I have to split single shard data into 4 shards. Later, I will add their replicates on other node also.

Comment: You split one shard, then split those two resulting shards again, leaving you with four actual shards located on the node. You can then move those by using `MOVEREPLICA`.